# Declaring and setting variables in Oracle for TOAD

Tags: oracle11g, toad

I'm new to Oracle and TOAD for Oracle but my experience is in MS SQL.

How can I set values for variables? This gives me an error (PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement) on line 1.

```
declare 
startdate date := to_date('01/10/2015','mm/dd/yyyy');
enddate date := to_date('01/16/2015','mm/dd/yyyy');

begin
select 
    blah, blah, blah
from table
where some_date between startdate and enddate;
end;
```

I've Googled, Binged and knocked around, I don't see what is wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: It's because you're missing the INTO string. PL/SQL is not like T-SQL, in that it's server based, and if you want the client to return something, you have to tell PL/SQL how to do that. You can't just run a select statement inside PL/SQL and expect it to display the results on your screen. What exactly are you trying to do here? (I ask, because normally, you would do something with the results - e.g. use the results to insert into/update/delete from another table, or run some other procedure etc.)

Comment: I'm trying to extract data. If I don't try to use variables, it works fine. It writes to the grid and I copy the output. I don't understand why many of the examples I see don't use any kind of INTO string.

Comment: If you're just trying to extract data for you to view, just use a SQL statement, no PL/SQL. If you want a rerunnable sql query with parameters, try using bind variables: `select ... from ... where some_col between :start_date and :end_date`. Toad should prompt you for the values of each of the bind variables. Regarding implicit cursors (which is what you were trying to do) and explicit cursors (which is what I suspect the examples you've seen are about), [this might be of some use](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/implicit-vs-explicit-cursors-in-oracle-plsql.php)

Comment: N.B. if you choose to go down the route of bind variables, make sure you either specify the format of the variable correctly in the pop up box, or let it be treated as a string (the default) and cater for that in the query. (e.g. `select ... from ... where some_col between to_date(:start_date_str, 'dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date(:end_date_str, 'dd/mm/yyyy');`

Comment: If, howerver, you're wanting to pass the results on to another program, you'll have to work out the best way of doing that. I would suggest a ref cursor would be the best way of doing that. (This basically creates a cursor pointer and passes that across to the calling program so it can fetch data directly from the cursor.) BTW. every dml operation in Oracle opens a cursor; I know that SQL Server treats cursors differently, but they're not something to be scared of in Oracle.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. Honestly, it's way more complicated than it's worth. I was simply looking for a way to provide multiple parameter values so I wouldn't have to read through entire SQL statements, looking for values to replace. When I tried using bind variables, nothing popped up asking for a value.

Comment: Make sure you've got the Substitution Variable Prompting (accessible from the right mouse menu) switched on, if you're using the & way of passing values in. If you're using bind variables though (eg. `select * from dual where dummy = :p1`) then it should just automatically pop up the prompt for the value(s).